# How to make an app that downloads root (like framaroot) for android?

Tags: android, linux, root

I am working on a design for a root app for android 4.3 - 5.1. Does anyone know what is needed so that the app roots the phone?

Answer (score 2):

My honest advice is: Develop something else instead.

Rooting a device via an app means actually using a security breach to get root privileges and place a superuser binary on the device.

Security breaches are considered hugely dangerous by hardware manufacturers (they really are *hugely* dangerous), which means they are exceptionally hard to find even for expert developers. Reading from your question, you are no such expert, so I really would advice you to look for another project. Try to do something you can realistically accomplish and your knowledge and projects will grow.